# Why isn't $P^A = A$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, oracle-machines

I have a question regarding oracles.

If I have the complexity class $P^A$ (with $P \subseteq A$), what is it's relationship to the class $A$?

I mean it should be trivial that $A \subseteq P^A$ for all $A$.

But the other way is interesting.
As far as I know, there are some $A$ such that $P^A = A$ (e.g. $P$ or $BPP$) and there are some $A$ such that they are not equal (or at least we don't know).

For example $P^{PP}$. Why isnt this class the same as $PP$?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you think that $P^{PP} = PP$? Do you have a proof in mind?

Comment: $P^{NP}$ contains coNP, which is conjectured to be different from NP.